Is it harram to hire an Escort?
I'm new to the religion and actively reading the Quran.
I wanted to ask.
Is it harram to hire an escort for spending time with you and having sex?
She's not part of a brothel, just independant.
Also, I'm engaged but my wife is many countries away, and something makes me feel like this would also make it harram, is that true?
sorry for asking such dumb questions.

It would save the community a lot of valuable time if you could refrain from asking such questions. Maybe because you are new to the fold of Islam you have such questions. Even a Google search of how Islam views "escort" service will provide you with the answers abuntly. And after you have done your own research and still have doubts and things to clarify, you can always ask here.

Allah ordered Muslims to guard their private part except from their spouse or right-hand possession (Slave girl owned solely by you].
It is clear from Surah Al Mu'minun 25 verse 5-6
He orders a Muslim man to marry 2, 3, 4, or if he fears he can't do justice then marry only one or satisfy himself with right-hand possession as per Surah Nisa 4 Verse 3
As for escorts, those women are fornicators who commit fornication for money which is haram as per consensus of scholars.
If you are unable to control your desire it is better to fast as prescribed by Allah's Messenger and also avoid anything that arouses a desire for sex in you.

In theory, there are also escort girls that only walk around with you, showing themselves just like a 100.000$ Luxury watch, a very expensive car or jewelry. That might be permissible, but how should a rich vain crazy guy do that when he does not demand her to go half naked?

@GyroGearloose No that is also not permissible. Read the first two para of my answers

"Read the first two para of my answers" ... please explain.

A person cannot be with a strange woman whether to show off or in intimacy except either she is his wife or right-hand possession.

"A person cannot be with a strange woman ... " ... so a tourist guide must not lead women? I guess I know what your are telling, and the main thing is how to read the "to be with" part.
